# Keep constant speed in one direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make a game where the player only controls the left and right movement of a ball  ([like rolling sky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNn6nJqmQ8A)). The ball should moving forward at all times at a constant speed. So far I have tried the following but I can only control the ball left and right when it is in the air (jumping).

Any help or links would be very much appreciated.

```
 float forwardVelocity = 20.0f

 void Update () 
 {
     if (gameConfig.currentGameState == GameConfig.CurrentGameState.LevelInPlay) 
     {
         handleMovement();
         handleJumping();
         deathDetection ();
     }
 }
 void handleJumping()
 {
     if ((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) && isGrounded)
     {
         rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight, rigidBody.velocity.z);
         jumpSound.Play();
     }
 }
 void handleMovement()
 {
     var moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
     Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     rigidBody.AddForce (movement * rotationSpeed);
     if (rigidBody.velocity.z < forwardVelocity) 
     {
         rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidBody.velocity.x, rigidBody.velocity.y, forwardVelocity);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think that is becouse you add force then override it before the velocity was updated.

Comment: Good catch. I will try to move them around and see if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this in the FixedUpdate method which is working well.

```
    void handleMovement()
{
    moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = 1.0f

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rigidBody.AddForce (movement * rotationSpeed);
}
```